# How to migrate a single (php||javascript||...) file in production without time constraints

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I have simple files `(php||javascript||...)` running in production 
`(apache+(php||javascript||...))`.

I am trying to think to the proper way of migrating a simple file
***while not stopping serving web clients***.

Possible influences are:

- Apache cached files:  I do not know how apache deal with files (php, img, ...).  Does it cache them, and check for update timestamp to reload, or does it reload on each http request ?
- Linux files are changed in an atomic manner: If I `cp` a file with new content, apache can only see the full content final save results of my command ?
- Apache execution process: Can I pause Apache, holding current requests, while copying new file versions.

I **imagine** the following:

- Have files, like php `require_once` file, named with versions (ex: `ABusinessClassD-v1.0.php`), support backward compatibility, and simply do a `cp` of new files one by one, going from bottom up (database, static files (img, ...), php files, javascript files, ...)
- Force refresh browser code on demand.

Imagination != as simple as this != Reality.

> Please, can somebody summarize globally simple manual steps to update
>   a simple file in an apache production, without stopping serving web
>   clients, in a manual intentionally slow process ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem... Can't you just modify what you need on your localhost and then deploy?

Comment: @elclanrs He's worried about his site losing integrity _during_ such a deployment. Might users see half-copied/uploaded HTML pages, images that no longer match, etc. He wants an atomic deployment without interrupting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sure way to guarantee no issues when moving over a PHP codebase would be to have two servers or two deployments on the same server.

You have Server 1 which contains your old code. Server 2 is set up with the new code. Then, your DNS records or load balancer/proxy settings are changed so your site is instead served from Server 2.

Or with one server, you configure Apache to serve your application from `/path/to/old`, and then set up your new version in `/path/to/new`. Then you change your Apache configuration to use `/path/to/new` for the application and restart the server.

If you ever need to use version numbers in file names (`ABusinessClassD-v1.0.php`) then you need to learn about version control software like Git or Mercurial.

Comment: Version control was only an example of how to differentiate between old and new files.  I do not believe git (for instance) would simplify a production process. Would it ?  Between lines, I understand that you position the solution at a higher node in the path serving process of each request. But then session cookies become the new issue.  Current clients must reconnect, which resemble as a shutdown on client perception.  How do big company do it ?

Comment: Session cookies will work just fine if you configure your session storage correctly.